# how do i install a configuration option under "system: tool

Tags: magento-1.7, system.xml

I don't have all the option under the "system" option and I need a configuration option to set up my google analytics.

Please can you help me add the configuration option.

Thank you

Comment: do you mean under system->configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics should already be in Magento 1.7. To find it you should look under `System->Configuration->Google Api`. Here you will find that you can activate the extension and set your account number.

After setting these values you should be good to go.

If you want to see how it adds the code to your page look at the layout and template files:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml
```

Comment: David, Thank you for your answer, the problem is that I don't have the option to choose configuration under the system tool . maybe I need to install or add this option ?

Comment: @irene under system->configuration->advanced->disable module output do you have `Mage_GoogleAnalytics` enabled?

Comment: I cant go to system-->configuration. I just don't have this option . I have only chache management and index management , that's the only 2 options that I have under "system"

Comment: @irene then I would suggest that your user does not have the correct role. Is it not a user with the role Administrator?

Comment: yes I am , I am the one that makes price changes and other products listing information, but I am not the one who installed the magento... can it be the problem ?

Comment: @irene it looks like your account is restricted so that it cannot see the items you need to.